# $\sum_{n = N+ 1}^\infty \sqrt{n}2^{-n/2} \leq C\sqrt{N}2^{-N/2} $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it true that there is some $C \in (0, \infty)$, such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}_1$,

$$
\sum_{n = N+ 1}^\infty \sqrt{n}2^{-n/2} \leq C\sqrt{N}2^{-N/2}
$$

If true, how can it be proved? If false, why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n = N+ 1}^\infty 2^{-n/2}\sqrt{n}=C_N2^{-N/2}\sqrt{N}
$$
$$
C_N=\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n/2}\sqrt{1+\frac{n}N} \leqslant\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n/2}\sqrt{1+n}=C
$$

Comment: Ugh, silly me! Thank you.